# Usage of "Like" vs "As"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrase-usage

In the following sentence:

> Dogs are not so wild like the wolfs or the lions are.

- Is using "like" in comparative grammatically correct here, or should it be "as" instead, when basically two things are compared.
- Also, should the verb to be (here "are") be used at the end?

Or should it be instead:

> Dogs are not as wild as the wolfs or the lions are.

- In this case should "are" at the end be used?

Comment: This is essentially a cross post of the same question at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470629/comparative-statment-as-as-with-the-verb-to-be-at-the-end). One or the other should be closed.

Comment: Got no answer in ELU, it's an English learners stuff, so kindly keep it open here.

Comment: Simply "Dogs are not as wild as wolves or lions." *as ... as* works well in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Both "like" and "as" can be be used for comparisons, though they aren't synonyms--see https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-like-and-as.html for a good overview of the differences.

While both of your uses of "as" and "like" are correct, your use of "so" does subtly change the meaning and implication of the sentence. To say:

> "Dogs are not so wild like lions."

indicates dogs aren't that wild, unlike lions which are wild. The sentence is a bit awkward and a more natural sounding English sentence might be:

> "Dogs are not so wild, unlike lions."

Contrastingly,

> "Dogs are not as wild as lions."

indicates that dogs might be wild, but are not as wild as lions. However, this is a subtle connotation difference and overall the message would be understood either way.

Regarding the use of "are" at the end, it's valid syntax and not grammatically incorrect, but it definitely isn't necessary and I wouldn't recommend using it for formal writing or speech.

Last little note: plural of "wolf" is "wolves" :)

Comment: How about the following, in your opinion:

"He did not play with cars LIKE the other boys in his class did." or should it be with "as"  nstead:

"He did not play with cars AS the other boys in his class did."

As far as I know, the first sentence with "like" is incorrect, and the second one with "as" is correct,

Tnx!